# Java Server Faces Ajax request doesn't work properly

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I use OpenFaces library and I want to execute some ajax request e.g. if checkbox is true display `TextArea`, but it doesn't work at all. The principle of operation is the same as in JSF standard lib. I will show You my code:

```
<o:selectBooleanCheckbox id="addOpis" value="#{ajaxBean.opis}">
    <o:ajax event="click" execute="addOpis" render="opisArea"/>
</o:selectBooleanCheckbox> 
<h:outputLabel for="dodajOpisCheckbox" value="zaznacz aby dodać opis" />
<o:inputTextarea id="opisArea" value="#{productBean.opis}" rendered="#{ajaxBean.opis}"/>
```

ManagedBean source:

```
@ManagedBean(name="ajaxBean")
@RequestScoped
public class AjaxBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean opis;

    public AjaxBean() {
    }

    public void setOpis(boolean opis) {
        this.opis = opis;
    }

    public boolean isOpis() {
        return opis;
    }

}
```

I looked for some solutions but my code it seems to be good, please help.

Comment: Is this code inside of <h:form> tag?

Comment: yes,the whole page is in `h:form` tag. To clarify the textarea appears when the page is refreshed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no element with id `opisArea` on page after loading, because `rendered` attribute is false at default.

The most easy way to fix it - put `opisArea` inside of element, which always would be rendered:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="addOpis" value="#{testBean.opis}">
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="addOpis" render="opisArea"/>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox> 
<h:outputLabel for="dodajOpisCheckbox" value="zaznacz aby dodać opis" />
<h:panelGroup id="opisArea" >
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{productBean.opis}" rendered="#{testBean.opis}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```